# Can read() and readlines() work together when reading a file in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a Python beginner, and I'm doing some tests of file operations.
I just read a file with `read()` and `readlines()`. Each of them works perfectly, respectively. However, when I add a `readlines()` to read the appointed file after `read()`, I surprisingly find that I can't read anything from the file using `readlines()`.

P.S. I tried to switch the places of them, and the latter function can't read anything from the file yet.

So, how do the functions actually work?

Below is my code:

```
filea = open('/Users/gssflyaway/Documents/web/echarts-2.2.7/LICENSE.TXT')
print filea.readlines()
print '-' * 50
print filea.read()
filea.close()
```

[the result by Pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taQM2.jpg)

Comment: Both methods read the whole file so after you call one of them there's nothing left to read for the other.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Paste the text itself into your question, either into a quote block, or use a code block to preserve formatting.

Comment: You mean both functions read "the left of the file" rather than the whole file? And how does the system define the concept "the left"?

Comment: BTW, since you are just starting to learn Python you _really_ should be learning Python 3. After 2020, Python 2 will not be supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files are read from the disk by moving a pointer (like a bookmark so that the file object knows where it left) around. A read operation advances the pointer and if you read the whole file, the pointer will be at the very end of the file. Same applies to both `readlines` and `read`. If you want to re-read the file, you can use `seek` to reset the pointer to the beginning to start a new round.

```
filea.seek(0)
```